# How can I make a file accessible to Azure container instance

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-container-instances

thanks in advance for your help. I am really new to docker and I am trying to deploy a container group to ACI using docker context and docker compose. I need a certain license file to be accessible when the instance starts.

I have tried quite a few things like adding the file to azure file share and blog and mounting it is as volume but no luck. I have added my docker compose file. Please guide me how can I achieve the above scenario?

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  api:
    image: myimagefromdockerhub 
    container_name: api
    deploy: 
      resources:
         reservations:
          cpus: '2'
          memory: 3G
    environment:
      Sqlname:*****
      SqlPass:*****
    volumes:
      - license:/app/extBin/unix_x64/cpu/license
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - api-network
    depends_on:
      - "db-postgres"
    restart: always

  db-postgres:
    image: bitnami/postgresql:14.5.0-debian-11-r35
    container_name: db-postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - postgre-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "db"
      POSTGRES_USER: "user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "****"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - api-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://api:41101/ || exit"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3

networks:
  api-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgre-data:
   driver: azure_file
   driver_opts:
      share_name: myfileshare
      storage_account_name: storageaccountname
  license:
   driver: azure_file
   driver_opts:
      share_name: license
      storage_account_name: storageaccountname
```

when I run docker compose up -d it deploys alright but the file is not present and postgre keeps terminating and restarting. I am more concerned about the file not being present.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reproducing the same in my environment using the below steps and got the results as expected. Check if you have followed all these steps and able to ressolve the issue.

As a first step, I created docker context using the command [`docker context create`](https://i.imgur.com/LMU1sGj.png) and set as the default context.
[image]

Next, **I have created a storage account with fileshare (tier=Hot) in the same resource group as the docker context** .

I have uploaded a sample certificate to the fileshare.

[image]

Next, I modified your Dockerfile slightly and ran using `docker-compose up` command and verfied whether the file existed in the azure portal as below.

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  api:
    image: nginx 
    container_name: api
    deploy: 
      resources:
         reservations:
          cpus: '2'
          memory: 3G
    volumes:
      - license:/app/extBin/unix_x64/cpu/license
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - api-network
    restart: always

networks:
  api-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  license:
   driver: azure_file
   driver_opts:
      share_name: license
      storage_account_name: licensestrgaccountvjy
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @GoonaBabu, thanks for the reply it really helped me. I guess it was because of the hot tier and also noticed the storage account I was mounting on was having a read-only access. I will mark this as accepted answer.